# Show that $x$ divides $a^n-1$ for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, ring-theory

Let $a>0$ be an algebraic integer and let $b\in\mathbb{Z}\neq0$. I'm trying to prove (or disprove) that if $a$ is a unit of $\mathbb{Z}[a]$, then there exists $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $b$ divides $a^n-1$ (as elements of $\mathbb{Z}[a]$).

If the quotient ring $\mathbb{Z}[a]/(b)$ is finite then this is easy since $a^n=1\mod (b)$ where $n$ is the order of the quotient ring. However, I can't prove that the quotient ring is finite.

Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: Sorry. I forgot to write that $a>0$. I'll edit the question

Comment: @Dietrich In that case, yes, for $n=4$.

Comment: @hardmath: Ah yes. That is also correct.

Comment: Isn’t $\mathbb Z[a]/(b)$ at most $b^n$ elements, where $n$ is the degree of the minimal rational polynomial for $a?$

Comment: I'm not sure what to make of $a\gt 0$ if algebraic integer $a$ is supposed to be a unit of $\mathbb Z[a]$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: Why?

Comment: @hardmath: Golden ratio for example

Comment: Because every element of $\mathbb Z[a]$ is of the form $a_0+a_1a+\cdots a_{n-1 }a^{n-1}$ with the $a_i\in Z,$ and a set of representatives modulo $b$ can be chosen with $0\leq a_i<b.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: I think that is correct. Thanks.

Comment: It makes a little more work if $\mathbb Z[a]$ means the algebraic integers of $\mathbb Q(a).$ @morphy22 But I think the ring is finite there, too.

Comment: More generally, see literature on rings that are *residually finite* (or satisfy FNP = *Finite Norm Property*) that we cite in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/330296/242).